# Get values from JSON encoded array string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My .php code in a file "fetchvalues.php" looks like this:

```php
echo json_encode(array($PostedDate.Places.$Company.$Designation.$ProjectDetails.$DesiredCandidate.$HRName.$HRContact.$Email));
```

This file is called by another file and the calling function looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Edit").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("fetchvalues.php?UpdateRecordID=" + $.cookie('UpdateRecordID'),
      function(data) {
        // Data retrieved in concatenated form. So we will break it and store values in array.
        var concatenatedvalues = new Array();
        concatenatedValues = data;
        alert(concatenatedValues);
      });
  });
});
```

The data is being returned successfully, but I am not following how get each array element through javascript. What modifications are needed in the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** I just reread your question and it looks like you intentionally concatenated the values. Since you are using `json_encode` it would be much better to send the values as an array, and simply access it in JavaScript.

```
echo json_encode(array($PostedDate, $Places, $Company, $Designation, $ProjectDetails, $DesiredCandidate, $HRName, $HRContact, $Email));
```

Then in JavaScript they would be accessed like this:

```
alert(data[1]); // Would alert the value of $Places
```

Comment: It is showing the entire record in the alert box not that particular column value.

Comment: @RPK, did you change your PHP to match what I posted? You were using `.` and I used `,` instead.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with your project!