# Return Multiples Array in JavaScript from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

In php I return this from a function:

```
return json_encode(array($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4));
```

Each array contains single elements, loaded lke this:

```
while ($obj = $DB->next($res)) {
    $array1[] = $obj->the_data;
}
```

Now in JavaScript, I alert `data[0]`, it shows me "["

Of course the entire `data` looks similar to this:

`[["element1", "element2", "element3"],["element1", "element2", "element2" ... etc`

Am I loading the `array`'s incorrectly in php?  or am I parsing them incorrectly in JavaScript?

- this is being returned in a jQuery Ajax `.post` call.
- I also am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962790/get-values-from-json-encoded-array-string) question as a reference

Comment: Did you set the dataType-argument to "json" in the $.post call?

Comment: @friedi no, see the answer below. that was it,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `data` is a string instead of an array. This suggests that you aren't decoding the JSON.

jQuery will do that automatically if the response from the server is marked as JSON.

By default PHP marks responses as HTML, you need to explicitly say you are returning JSON:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: Ugh, you are correct.  I completely forgot about this `}, 'json');` param in my .post call.  I had nothing whcih I guess defaults to text or html.

Comment: @KickingLettuce — jQuery defaults to "Believing the server". Overriding that is a hack to get around the server lying about what it is returning. You should set the content-type header of the response.

Comment: Had no idea, I thought that was perfectly legitimate.  Not sure where I would put the `header` call in my php file.  It has many functions being used for ajax returns.  Not all are encoded with `json`.

Comment: You might want to look at the MVC pattern.